# HTML, CSS Horizontal navigation bar filling up

Tags: html, css

I want to change horizontal navigation bar go through a line to other edge in the same color.

**Expected:**

[image: HTML,CSS WEBPAGE SCREEN SNAP]

**What I got:**

[image: MY WEBPAGEs SNAP]

To make it happen, I tried entirely different ways like：

- adding more buttons
- using horizontal line with same color

All attempts failed.

Can anyone help me to make it happen?

This is my code:

```css
.ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.li {
  float: left;
}

.li a {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.li a:hover {
  background-color: #9900cc;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="EN">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles/styles.css">
  <title>My shopping cart</title>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="ul">
  <li class="li"><a href="url.com">Home</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="url.com">News</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="url.com">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="url.com">About</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `<nav>` to enclose the `<ul>`.

```css
nav {
    background: #333;
    overflow: auto;
}

.ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.li {
  float: left;
}

.li a {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.li a:hover {
  background-color: #9900cc;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="EN">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles/styles.css">
  <title>My shopping cart</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="ul">
            <li class="li"><a href="url.com">Home</a></li>
            <li class="li"><a href="url.com">News</a></li>
            <li class="li"><a href="url.com">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="li"><a href="url.com">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```